# Flink Job goes too much busy with less amount of data

Tags: apache-flink, large-data

I am configuring a Flink Job that can handle almost 1 million data per second, I have started with below configuration
CPU: 4 cores
Memory: 2GB
Task Slots: 4

with only 30k logs per second
But my job still goes too much busy and have a much backpressure,
As far as I read that Flink can handle very large amount of data But here is some contradict, I might miss out some of the configuration, So can anybody help me to figure out it would be highly appreciate

Thank you in advance

[image]

I have tried by increasing a memory and parellelism but it didn't work for me, I want to understand that is it expected like with this configuration this result is okay or I should configure the job in any other way.

Comment: Without additional details about your data, what processing you're doing in join wit the broadcast stream, what sink you're using, your version of Flink, etc. etc. your question is too vague to answer explicitly. I've provided some general notes in an answer below.

Comment: I am using sink as a RedPanda topic, Verion 1.17.1. I am broadcasting rules (Fliter or transform rule). I have almost 20+ rule, and 50+ column in log,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a workflow reading from Kafka, doing a broadcast-stream based enrichment, and writing to Hudi, I got a rate of about 13K records/sec/core. This is with optimizations like using faster-serde for deserializing records from Kafka, etc.

So with 4 cores, 30K records/second is in the right ballpark.

Note that increasing parallelism without increasing the number of cores available won't help, and typically hurts your throughput.